# Magento 2 Custom Widget set template data not showing at frontend

Tags: magento2, widgets

I am working to create custom widget in custom extension. I followed [this](http://www.venustheme.com/how-to-create-magento-2-widget/) to create widget in my custom extension.
All working fine but data not showing in the template
 `$this->setTemplate('widget/viewed_list.phtml');`

Below my code:

> Technologymindz/Instagramfeed/Block/Widget/Instawidget.php

```
<?php
namespace Technologymindz\Instagramfeed\Block\Widget;

class Instawidget extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface
{

    public function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('widget/viewed_list.phtml');

    }


}
```

> Technologymindz/Instagramfeed/etc/widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Magento/Widget/etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget id="tm_customwidget" class="Technologymindz\Instagramfeed\Block\Widget\Instawidget">
        <label translate="true">Instagram Feeds</label>
        <description>Show Your Instagram Feeds Anywhere</description>
        <parameters>
                        <parameter name="tmfeedtoshow" xsi:type="select" required="true" visible="true">
                            <label>Show Latest Feeds</label>
                            <options>
                                <option name="default" value="12" selected="true">
                                    <label translate="true">12</label>
                                </option>
                                <option name="list" value="24">
                                    <label translate="true">24</label>
                                </option>                              
                            </options>
                        </parameter>
            <parameter name="tmview_type" xsi:type="select" required="true" visible="true">
                            <label>Select View Type</label>
                            <options>
                                <option name="default" value="widget/viewed_grid.phtml" selected="true">
                                    <label translate="true">Grid View</label>
                                </option>
                                <option name="list" value="widget/viewed_list.phtml">
                                    <label translate="true">List View</label>
                                </option>                              
                            </options>
                        </parameter>
        </parameters>                
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

> Technologymindz/Instagramfeed/view/frontend/widget/viewed_list.phtml

```
<?php
echo $this->getTmview_type();
echo 'Welcome';
?>
```

Data output not showing for `viewed_list.phtml` but if i set something in Block `_toHtml()`function than it shows.

```
public function _toHtml()
    {
        return '<p class="hello">Hello world!</p>';
    }
```

Hope this is clear, I want to manage output in `.phtml` not in Block

Answer (score 2):

For me it was Peter's solution, but also move your template file to **`/view/templates/widget/viewed_list.phtml`**

```
public function _toHtml()
{
    $this->setTemplate('widget/viewed_list.phtml');
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

And `/view/templates/widget/viewed_list.phtml` instead of `/view/widget/viewed_list.phtml`

Answer (score 1):

i did removed `_toHtml` function

Here the solution fix for me:

```
protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct(); 
        $this->setTemplate('widget/viewed_list.phtml');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your modification of the `_toHtml` you are both preventing the logic from the parent class from triggering and stopping it returning anything. The reason your example at the bottom works is that your method actually returns content. There are a few different variations, but something along the lines of this should work:

```
public function _toHtml()
{
    $this->setTemplate('widget/viewed_list.phtml');

    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

Comment: :-( this didn't work for me, i did follow http://www.venustheme.com/how-to-create-magento-2-widget/ is this good to use?

Comment: I've honestly not use Magento 2 much, but that example looks wrong to me, from what I'm seeing in the core code.

Answer (score 0):

Having had the same problem with this exact tutorial, and several cloned versions of it that appear high up the search listings, I came to the conclusion that it's a pretty buggy and poor quality example that's been rush-written for SEO.

I eventually found this widget tutorial that seems far more accurate: https://magently.com/blog/magento-2-widgets-tutorial/ - I'm sure there are others.  Lots of the differences make me think the venustheme one follows bad practise.

An example in your/venustheme's code is `../../../Magento/Widget/etc/widget.xsd` instead of `urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd`.  Both work, but the latter seems to follow the practise of the core modules.

Answer (score 0):

```
class BannerWidgetBlock extends Template implements BlockInterface
{
    const DEFAULT_SELECTION = 1;

    protected $_template = "widget/banner-widget.phtml";
}
```